# Comparing Strings in Java .equals()

Tags: java, string, compare, equals, joptionpane

I'm trying to filter the user's input to make sure its a max of 4 digits and it's not an empty string. Whether I leave it blank or I enter a number, `!strInput.equals(null)` still comes up true. Am I comparing the string incorrectly?

I also tried: `!strInput.equals("")` , `strInput != null` , and `strInput != ""` though I think it should be .equals(...) since I'm trying to compare values.

```
        private void updateFast() {
            String strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many?");

            if (!strInput.equals(null) && strInput.matches("\\d{0,4}"))
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Please Re-enter");
                updateFast();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Instead of `!strInput.equals(null)` use `strInput != null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
if (!strInput.equals(null) && strInput.matches("\\d{0,4}"))
```

To:

```
if (strInput != null && strInput.matches("\\d{1,4}"))
```

No need to check if String is empty, the regex checks that.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just left it as strInput.matches("\\d{1,4}")). Thanks for the help, I didn't think about that

Comment: @OscarF If the strInput is null, you will get NullPointerException. You must check for null before the regex match.

Comment: I put the whole if else statement in a try catch. That took care of the NullPointerException. Is it wrong to do it this way?

Comment: Not wrong, but let a exception been through has a higher CPU cost. Better check first.

Comment: I see. I just tried it the way you said but the problem is, when you press cancel or close, you get the error message and you're pretty much stuck there. The method just calls itself infinitely unless you input a valid number.

Comment: So you need a "else if". Check the docs for JOptionPane.showInputDialog return options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61811/discussion-between-diogosantana-and-oscar-f).

Answer (score 1):

If you leave an input value blank, the string will be "" not null. You will need to use `!strInput.equals("")` to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

Just in case.. you might want to `.trim()` your string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strInput != null && !strInput.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

> strInput!=null && strInput.trim().length()>0

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (!strInput.isEmpty() ...
if (strInput != null && strInput.length() > 0 ...
```

I hope this has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing it wrong.

When you pass an object to String.equals(Object o), one of the things it will do is to check if the parameter passed is an instance of String.class. Since you are passing null, it will always return false.

You should check to see if your string is null and then if it is empty. String.class does have that method.

So:

```
if(strInput != null && !strInput.isEmpty() && strInput.matches("\\d{0,4}")) {
    // do something...
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Please Re-enter");
    updateFast();
}
```