# Is this a bug or by design for abstract classes in Groovy?

Tags: inheritance, groovy, abstract-class

I have this code in Groovy, is this a bug or it is by design:

```
abstract class One {
    String content
    String description

    String returnContent(){
        return content
    }
}

class Two extends One {
    String getContent() {
        content ?: description
    }
}

Two two = new Two(description:"this is my description")

assert two.returnContent() == "this is my description"
```

I would expect the assert to pass but actually is not, so it seems that when calling *content* is not calling the *getContent()* method of the instance.

Comment: Bug?  No, it's your code.  Assume that you're the problem; first, last, and always.  Why would it call getContent()?  Your code invokes returnContent().    Does this even compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Strings in Java .equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007630/comparing-strings-in-java-equals)

Comment: This is just an example. I am just trying to know why when accessing to content field (which in Groovy is usually the same as calling the getter), is not actually working like this for abstract classes. @duffymo, I can be the problem so many times, but not this time.

Comment: @FranGarcía Provide an example that demonstrates a "problem"

Comment: If you run the example I add to the post, it will fail and I think it shouldn't.

Comment: When you say "it shouldn't fail" yo have to tell us why do you think so  or how does it violate the specs.

Comment: Bug in a scripting language that's been out there for how long?   You think you're the first to spot such a thing?  It's more likely that the problem is your code and your expectation of what should happen.

Comment: @duffymo I am not stating it was a bug, I am just asking.

Comment: @Stultuske it's Groovy, it's wrong to link this issue, as it's totally unrelated. In groovy, you compare string with `==`

Comment: @JérémieB earlier, it wasn't tagged with groovy, but with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification says [here](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties) :

> Properties are accessed by name and will call the getter or setter
>   transparently, unless the code is in the class which defines the
>   property ... It is worth noting that this behavior of accessing the
>   backing field directly is done in order to prevent a stack overflow
>   when using the property access syntax within a class that defines the
>   property.

So returnContent access the field directly, it doesn't call getContent().

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug and it is by design like that. Not a surprise though because you are referring to a member in an abstract class which owns the member. There is no instance and no automatic generation of getContent.